# Upon prediction, my loaded model is giving me an AttributeError

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, tf.keras

I'm fairly new to Tensorflow and Machine Learning in general but I know enough that I've built a small model. Although, when loaded and I use `model.predict`, I get an attribute error:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

checkpoint_path = "training_1/cp.ckpt"
# Hyperparamters
vocab_size = 2000
embedding_dim = 16
max_length = 1
trunc_type = "post"
padding_type = "post"
oov_tok = "<OOV>"
training_size = 100

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(
        vocab_size, embedding_dim, input_length=max_length),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation="softmax")
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
              optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])

model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)


test = ["Example of text here"]


prediction = model.predict(test)
print(prediction)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ModelTest.py", line 36, in <module>
    prediction = model.predict(test)
  File "/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1060, in predict
    x, check_steps=True, steps_name='steps', steps=steps)
  File "/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 2651, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 334, in standardize_input_data
    standardize_single_array(x, shape) for (x, shape) in zip(data, shapes)
  File "/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 334, in <listcomp>
    standardize_single_array(x, shape) for (x, shape) in zip(data, shapes)
  File "/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 265, in standardize_single_array
    if (x.shape is not None and len(x.shape) == 1 and
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Comment: Check this https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#arguments_7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the input you're giving is in the correct format for the model you build. In your case, an `Embedding` layer expects a 2D tensor. The data should be a numpy array that looks something like this: `[[0, 2, 64], [24, 6, 8]]`. Each number there represents a word, and each sequence of numbers represents a phrase. The whole tensor represents a batch of sequences. In my example, that's a batch of 2 sequences, each with 3 words.

What you need to do is tokenize `"Example of text here"` using the correct vocabulary for the model you're loading. Once you do, you'll get an array like `[[3, 8, 4, 6]]`, where each of those numbers corresponds to one of the words in `"Example of text here"`. How to tokenize it correctly depends on how the data it was trained on was tokenized, and we don't know that without knowing where you got `training_1/cp.ckpt` from.

Comment: Ohh I did try tokenizing and padding to match the data in my model but I thought I was doing it wrong as my values were all over the place.

Comment: @deluxeme The values should look all over the place. Each number in a tokenized sequence is just an arbitrary ID for a word in the vocabulary. When I tokenize `"example of text here"` with the vocabulary I happen to be using for my project right now, I get `[460, 4, 3001, 130]`. Yours will look different (unless you're using keras' builtin IMDB dataset), but it should look similarly random.

Comment: I understand that the words are tokenized but the output of the model.predict is: [[0.30352557 0.26858705 0.42788738]]
Does this mean that out of the 3 classes. It thinks the third class is most fitting?

Comment: @deluxeme Yes, that is what that means.

Comment: Sorry for the barrage of questions but should I be using the same tokenizer instance I used for the initial model or do I create a new one?

Comment: @deluxeme You should use the same one. In general, two different tokenizer instances will have different internal dictionaries. If the tokenizers are fit on the same dataset then they _may_ end up with equivalent dictionaries, but it's best to not rely on that.

Comment: Ahhh, it makes sense now. I thought it was weird that it was giving weird predictions. Thank you for guiding me through this.

Comment: @deluxeme No problem, happy I could help!